# NIFI ConvertExcelToCsvProcessor error

Tags: apache-nifi

When I try using the ConvertExcelToCsvProcessor to convert excel(xlsx) to csv, it is giving some error. I have attached the screenshot of the error. Could anyone please help.

Here is the log for the same
10:23:26 EDTWARNING1a4d1c5d-1317-11fb-23b0-c2732fc64051
ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor[id=1a4d1c5d-1317-11fb-23b0-c2732fc64051] Processor Administratively Yielded for 1 sec due to processing failure

10:23:28 EDTERROR1a4d1c5d-1317-11fb-23b0-c2732fc64051
ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor[id=1a4d1c5d-1317-11fb-23b0-c2732fc64051] Failed to process incoming Excel document: java.lang.NullPointerException

10:23:28 EDTERROR1a4d1c5d-1317-11fb-23b0-c2732fc64051
ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor[id=1a4d1c5d-1317-11fb-23b0-c2732fc64051] ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor[id=1a4d1c5d-1317-11fb-23b0-c2732fc64051] failed to process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=7709f253-3a07-47f2-84d9-c61ba162f2e7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1503325407951-1265, container=default, section=241], offset=0, length=2429403],offset=0,name=24182659482562736,size=2429403] transfer relationship not specified; rolling back session: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandlingException: StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=7709f253-3a07-47f2-84d9-c61ba162f2e7,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1503325407951-1265, container=default, section=241], offset=0, length=2429403],offset=0,name=24182659482562736,size=2429403] transfer relationship not specified

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`transfer relationship not specified` - means you did not provide the relationship where to transfer the result.

Comment: Thanks for the repy.I have added puthdfs processor after exceltocsv processer. Even then it is giving the same error. Could you please help.

Comment: please modify your original question with the following notes: `1)` find in the file `<NIFI_HOME>/logs/nifi-app.log` the error that you have on the screen and add it into question with full stacktrace, `2)` make a screenshot of your flow with all incoming and outgoing connections of `excelToCsvProcessor`, `3)` make sure that all outgoing relationships (failure,original,success) of the  the `excelToCsvProcessor` are connected to another processors or terminated in the settings of the processor.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the my question, could you please check now and help me on the same.

Comment: ok. and what about `failure` and `original` relationships? are they terminated? because on the screenshot i see only `success`.

Comment: Yes they are terminated

Comment: please add the full stacktrace of the error. all those `at ...` and `caused by ...`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug; namely that some error during processing (generating the NullPointerException) is causing the code to exit before handling the flow files correctly. As @daggett mentioned, can you add the full stacktrace from the logs? I can write a Jira case to fix the problem once I know more about where it is happening.